# How to filter data with conditions on one column?

Tags: r, data-analysis

Goal: Retain in ss16wa only those rows where "COW" (a column name) is 1, 6, or 7.

I tried using `COW == 1 || COW ==6 || COW == 7` which ran into errors. 
The image below, line 33, shows the new option that I have used which seems to work, but also cause an warning message of some sort.

If anyone knows a better solution then it will be much appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` in the `filter` statement as `==` is used for comparing with a single element (or length equals 1).  For more than one element in a `vector`, use `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(ss16wa, WAGP < 50000, SEMP< 50000, PINCP < 100000, COW %in% c(1, 6, 7))
```